# Appsflyer Crash : Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver.java line 43

Tags: android, crash, crashlytics, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I am getting a Crash which is reported in Crashlytics for com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver.onReceive in MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver.java class

This Crash is been reported for few users in all the android verisons

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method 藡(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V in class Lcom/appsflyer/AppsFlyerLib; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib' appears in /data/app/com.rapido.passenger-1/base.apk)
       at com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver.java:43)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3112)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1627)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it seems to be an obfuscation issue (looking at the method name `藡`)

What is the SDK version being used? Are there any proGuard (or other tool) rules configured for AppsFlyer? 
If not I would suggest adding a `-keep class com.appsflyer.** { *; }` rule.

If you do not wish to share any additional information publicly, you can open a ticket with support@appsflyer.com, with the SDK version, any obfuscation related information and a link to this thread.